# What is the proper react app file structure?

Tags: reactjs

I have a question about a proper, or standard way to structure a react app.

For example, I always initiate my react app using `create-react-app`. In the `src` folder inside `create-react-app`, there are `index.js` `index.css`, `App.js`, and `App.css` files by default (there are couple more files, but I will disregard for now).

However, I do not quite get how the structure works. Isn't `index.js` the main page for the app? Why is `index.js` connected to `App.js`? Also, if I want to add more pages and components in the app, how should I structure it? I know that there needs to be `components` folder inside `src` folder, and a `pages` folder for different page files (such as `page2.js`)

I have a strong feeling that maybe I am completely going in the wrong way. I was doing some research about it, and it seemed like every tutorial had a different structure. Do I structure it however I want? If so, what is the most proper way?

Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't really a "right" way to structure your app. Really, you adapt based on your project's needs. With that said, I can probably help clarify a few things for you, and give you something to get you started.

1. index.js is the entry point for your javascript application. In it, your react application is typically initiated. Look for a line with `reactDom.render(<App />, 'root);` This says, find an html element with id root in the corresponding html file (the is found during the magical build process that is currently hidden away by create react app), and swap out what react renders into html for that node.
2. It's very common to break react components into three groups: (1) Containers; (2) Components; and (3) Pages. For simpler react apps, containers are usually responsible for getting data, laying out a series of components, and passing data to them. Components are meant to encapsulate some particular functionality that can then be re-used / layed-out in a container. Pages then are a collection of 1 or more containers that can logically be grouped together in a Page. I recommend leveraging something like [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/) to make your life much easier. It will allow you to say, for this route, render this component.
   **Know that component is an overloaded term here, because it is used to mean one thing architecturally as I just described, but at the same time all three architectural types are all just react components at the end of the day. They are just categories of them to help you think with.**

I highly recommend starting off by reading the intro docs for [react](https://reactjs.org/).
If you are coming from an OOP background, I put [this](http://reactintro4devs.surge.sh)
 together a while back for some java colleagues looking to dabble in react. I try to 80/20 accuracy for efficacy in getting you moving.

Comment: Hmm... I see. Thank you for clarifying! It's still a little hard to fully understand, but I think this is a good starting point for me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

`index.js` isn't the "main page for the app", it's the script which loads your app into the DOM. `App.js` is usually the starting point for the actual content of the application (i.e. shows, or decides to show, whatever is seen when app loads).

In terms of folder structure within `src/` there really isn't a 'standard', as you're finding out. You can structure things however you like. Best way is to look at a bunch of different tutorials and open source React repos and see how they do it (where are the components, where are the constants, where are the scripts, how do they do the subfolders in these, etc.) and pick whichever ones makes the most sense to you.

A good choice might be, for your first couple of personal React projects, try a few different structures and get a feel for which makes things easiest for you.

Basically there's no "correct" way of doing it. Any way which is logical, intuitive, easy to navigate and will remain so as your code base grows is an acceptable structure.

Answer (score 0):

One of the common file structures of the `src` folder is [grouping by features or routes](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-structure.html#grouping-by-features-or-routes).

Another approach is about having the files [grouped by types](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-structure.html#grouping-by-features-or-routes)(components, API, utils, etc.).

The first one is a better way for me, as the second one becomes hard to navigate when the project is too big.

There is also an architecture called [ARc](https://arc.js.org/). It can help you build and structure your components by dividing them into groups:

- atoms
- molecules
- organisms
- templates
- pages

Comment: He wont know what actions and reducers are yet. and given the context api / hooks, he can probably get pretty far without ever seeing a need for redux now.